# Things to consider while adopting newer version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration

1. Which all things should be considered while adopting any newer version of Visual Studio? E.g. Moving from VS 2015 to VS 2017 OR VS 2017 to latest VS 2019.
2. What problems may come if all developers are not using the same Visual Studio version?
3. Generally speaking, can CI pipeline restrict us for whatever reason?

Note: All my projects are built on .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinions:

1. If you use Microsoft Azure Tools, when you open the solution for the first time in a new VS version, it will ask you to upgrade the project to the new Microsoft Azure Tools. That means your other developers, if you want them to continue see that .Azure project, need to upgrade the Microsoft Azure Tools version too.
2. You can have different versions of the language.
   In Visual Studio 2017 you can use C# 7.0 while in Visual Studio 2015, C# 6.0 is the latest acceptable version. That means if the developer who is using VS2017 is writing C# 7.0 code, it won't compile on the developer's machine who is using VS2015.
3. Same as above. Your build agent should be have the latest version of VS installed. If he tries to build a project having C# 7.0 while he uses VS2015's MSBuild, an error would be thrown in the pipeline.

Those are the problems we have encountered. It is best that all the team migrates to the same Visual Studio version (hope the highest one) because you will have a lot of new features available for all.